# Cleaning up backup files on ubuntu server

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

We have a RHEL Linux server running two programs whose backups get copied over to another server running Ubuntu Linux. There is a "cleanup" script running in a cron job that is supposed to delete these backups that are more than ten days old but it is not working. In fact I can't get it to work even running it manually. Script is below-

```
#!/bin/bash
# bash shell script to cleanup jira backup files
# The script will remove files that are 10 days or older 
#
# Remove jira backup files
for FILE in `find /usr/backup/jira -mtime +10`
do echo $FILE
/bin/rm -f $FILE 2>/dev/null
done
```

When I run this script at the command prompt- ./cleanup_jira.sh nothing happens; I just move down to the command prompt. I have root owning all the folders and files involved. This was all setup years ago to run by a different user, but apparently has not been working for quite awhile so I modified it all to be run as root. I do not get a mail message to root either when I try to run it.

Any ideas please respond.

Thanks for your time,

John Ellis

Answer (score 1):

No need for a for loop:

```
find /usr/backup/jira -type f -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

If this is not working look in the specified directory if there are files that are older than 10 days.

Comment: Maybe add a `-v` to the `rm` for feedback. (Or use `-print -delete` instead of `-exec ...`.)

Comment: Well I'm embarrassed to say that I figured out the problem; I had copied a couple of the backup files over to my PC for testing purposes and then when I copied them back over it updated the 'Last Modified" date & time so the script didn't see them as being as old as they actually were. Thanks for the replies and better script and suggestions! My only defense is that I am not a scripter and had very little linux experience until I took this job. My Bad